# $f , g : X \to Y$ continuous functions , where $X;Y$(with order topology) are topological spaces ; then $A:=\{x \in X : f(x) \ge g(x) \}$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $Y$ be  an ordered topological space equipped with the odrer topology $f , g : X \to Y$ be continuous functions , where $X$ is a topological space ; then is it true that $A:=\{x \in X : f(x) \ge g(x) \}$ is closed in $X$ ?

Comment: Is the topology on $Y$ supposed to be the order topology?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes , the order topology

Comment: @SouvikDey Please edit that directly into the question, for clarity. Without it, answers as now by Somabha Mukherjee re main valid ...

Comment: Of course, I didn't realize that he was talking of the order topology.

Answer (score 3):

In $Y\times Y$ the set 
$$\{\,(x,y)\in Y^2\mid x<y\,\}=\bigcup_{t\in Y}(-\infty,t)\times(\sup(-\infty,t),+\infty)$$
is open (why do we need the supremum, why can we use the supremem?), hence $A:=\{\,(x,y)\in Y^2\mid x\ge y\,\}$ is closed. Your set is the inverse image of $A$ under the continuous map
$$X\stackrel \Delta\longrightarrow X\times X\stackrel{(f,g)}\longrightarrow Y\times Y  $$
hence closed.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let X be the real line, equipped with the usual metric topology, and Y also be the real line, now equipped with the trivial topology (empty set, Y). Let the ordering in Y be the natural ordering in reals. Note that every function from X to Y is continuous. Let f be identically 0 and g be -1 on (0,1) and 2 outside (0,1). Then, your A = (0,1), which is not closed in X.

Comment: Your space $Y$ isn’t a linearly ordered space with the order topology, so your example doesn’t apply.